# Prove that $a$ is a cluster point of $E$ $\iff$ for each $r>0$, $E\cap B_r(a)$ \ $\{a\}$ is nonempty.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, self-learning

**Question:**

Let $E$ be a subset of $\Bbb R^n$

Prove that $a$ is a cluster point of $E$ $\iff$ for each $r>0$, $E\cap B_r(a)$ \ $\{a\}$ is nonempty.

---

**definiton:**

A point $a \in \Bbb R^n$ is cluster point of $E$ if $E\cap B_r(a)$ contains infinitely manypoints for every $r>0$

---

Please can someone prove this? Thanks.

Comment: What is your definition of cluster point?

Comment: I have already written. @Kunnysan

Comment: I am sorry, I thought you wished to prove that!

Comment: No No, because of me.  I underlined the question. @Kunnysan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $\implies$ part:

Suppose there is some $r>0$ such that $E\cap B_r(a)$ contains no point except $a$. This leads to contradiction to your definition of cluster point.

For $\impliedby$ part:

If, $a$ is not a cluster point then there would exist a $r>0$ such that, $E\cap B_r(a)$ contains finitely many points, say $\{x_1...,x_n\}$ apart from $a$. Take, $s=\min\{d(a,x_i)\}$. Clearly $E\cap B_s(a)$ \ $\{a\}$ is empty, contradiction!

Comment: I understand everything. But, Sorry, I dont understand the last sentence. You said that" clearly this set is empty" but how? Can you explain there a little bit. Thanks:)

Comment: If you take $r$ as said, you will avoid all the 'finitely many points' and already $a$ is removed, So it is an empty set.

Comment: Maybe it's better if you take $s$ or some other letter as the minimum since you already used $r$ beforehand.

Comment: Thanks Stefan! Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** Just one direction needs a proof

$\Leftarrow$ by contraposition: suppose that  $E\cap B_r(a)\setminus\{a\}$ contains finitely many points $x_1,\ldots,x_s$ for some $r>0$  and let $d=\min_{i}d(a,x_i)$. Prove that $E\cap B_{d/2}(a)\setminus\{a\}$ is the empty set.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer şs the similar to Kunnysan's answer. I understand :)

Comment: The reason why this set is empty that is $E\cap B_{d/2}$ contains No point because of the choose of $r$. Thus, this set is empty. Is it? Right? @SamiBenRomdhane

Comment: @B11b In fact because of the choose of radius $d/2$ with the definition of $d$.

Comment: One can also take $d$ instead of $d/2$ unless your balls are closed.

Comment: Yes there's no problem  since the ball $B_d(a)$ is open and therefore just there's a point on its boundary.

Comment: Excellent, as usual!

Answer (score 2):

Let $a$ be a limit point of $E$, that is for each $r>0$ the ball $B_r(a)$ intersects $E\setminus\{a\}$. If $x_1\in B_r(a)\cap E\setminus\{a\}$, then choose $r_1< d(x_1,a)$, so $B_{r_1}(a)\cap E\setminus\{a\}$ doesn't contain $x_1$. But $B_{r_1}(a)\setminus\{a\}$ still intersects $E$, so you can choose an $x_2\in B_{r_1}(a)\cap E\setminus\{a\}$. Repeat this process and you get an infinite sequence of points in $B_{r}(a)\cap E\setminus\{a\}$.

What is actually used here is the property that the intersection of all neighborhoods of $a$ equals $\{a\}$. A topological space with this property is called a $T_1$-space.

Comment: Than you but your answer is at a little bit advanced level. Instead, thank you

Comment: My answer proves a bit more, namely that there is a sequence in $E$ converging to $a$, but it uses the axiom of choice ... even more advanced maths :-)